# How to display fonts like dafont.com

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I am using a below code in a while loop so it will show text as image when page come.

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

But its giving me error i have tried it with below code also.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","databasename");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_demo";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    { ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" ><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><img src="txt2img.php?txt=<?php echo $row[1]; ?>&font=<?php echo $row[2]; ?>" border="0"></td>           
        </tr>
   <?php }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Note:- I want to show fonts like dafont.com site. Please help i have tried this a lot of time and its not working fine.

Comment: So, is your question if we can guess the error and provide a timely resolution?

Comment: share your error

Comment: It show me a blank page and give message it contain error.